# Uwp не работают AdaptiveTrigger в VisualState

Tags: xaml, uwp, адаптивность, adaptive-design

Не работают триггеры , пробовал все что угодно , и разные свойства , и названия менял , ничего не работает , даже ничего не происходит . Цель триггеров сделать так чтобы при минимальной ширине стекпанелы располагались сверху-вниз , а при максимальной по горизонтали. Использовать стекпанел вместо грида не могу , так как правый стекпанел должен быть по центру оставшегося окна.

```
<ScrollViewer Margin="13,10,0,0" Height="450">
                <Grid>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Maximized">
                                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="600"/>
                                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="TopStackSettings.Grid.RowSpan" Value="2"/>
                                    <Setter Target="TopStackSettings.Grid.Column" Value="0"/>
                                    <Setter Target="PanelAboutProgrammInfo.Grid.RowSpan" Value="2"/>
                                    <Setter Target="PanelAboutProgrammInfo.Grid.Column" Value="1"/>
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Minimized">
                                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="0"/>
                                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="TopStackSettings.Grid.Row" Value="0"/>
                                    <Setter Target="TopStackSettings.Grid.ColumnSpan" Value="2"/>
                                    <Setter Target="PanelAboutProgrammInfo.Grid.Row" Value="1"/>
                                    <Setter Target="PanelAboutProgrammInfo.Grid.ColumnSpan" Value="2"/>
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="500"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <StackPanel x:Name="TopStackSettings" Orientation="Vertical">
                        
                    </StackPanel>

                    <StackPanel x:Name="PanelAboutProgrammInfo" Height="450">
                       
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </ScrollViewer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема заключалась в том что для AttachedProperty нужно писать вот так

```
<Setter Target="TopStackSettings.(Grid.RowSpan)" Value="2"/>
```